# npm v9: -- does not pass arguments to script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

All of a sudden, if I run

```
npm run dev -- --host
```

the `dev` script is invoked without the `--host argument`. Seems like `--` has stopped working.
Is it a feature in npm v9? I hope not, and couldn't find anything about this in the changelog...
Node 18.12.0, npm 9.5.0.
If I switch to Node 14 (with nvm for Windows), it still works.